# ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver but it's in the classpath

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DngzL.png)

[I have this Exception but the Jar file are in the referenced libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VbQ.png)

I dont't know where is the problem. The code is alright and I have added all in the build path.
String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

```
final String DBMS = "jdbc:mysql";

final String SERVER="localhost";

final String DATABASE = "mapDB";

final int PORT=3306; 

final String USER_ID = "MapUser";

final String PASSWORD = "map";

Connection conn;//gestisce una connessione 

private void initConnection() throws DatabaseConnectionException {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);/
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(DBMS + "://" + SERVER + ":" + PORT + "/" + DATABASE,USER_ID,PASSWORD);
    }catch(SQLException ex) {
        throw new DatabaseConnectionException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6VbQ.png) shows you have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar` on your classpath.

When looking for that file in the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java), there are many `5.1.x` versions, but not `5.1.7`.

It would seem that `5.1.7` is flawed and have been retracted.

Try using another `5.1.x` version, e.g. [the latest](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html), which currently is  `5.1.46`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are different versions of MySQL JDBC connectors, as the second print shows.

Maybe the existence of 2 references to the same lib is causing the ClassNotFoundException, or your project's build is not up to date.

I suggest you to keep only one version of the connector on the references of your project, clear and build the project again.

Comment: Yes. But I realized I had another project that has the same String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME and do the same thing. Is this the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe changing the reference order on the classpath can solve this. Try putting the connector reference up on the classpath, like in this print: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zjqPr.png

Comment: Also, if you're using Maven or Gradle, try to build the project on the command line, like: `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar, just keep mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

Comment: Yes. But I realized I had another project that has the same String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME and do the same thing. Is this the problem? I must remove this project from eclipse? There is another solution?

Comment: If you keep both version then you have to check you import statements: import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
and import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;                                                       
 since in version 8.0.11 Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. T